Libreoffice writer2latex extension fails to load with java error

writer2latex has always worked in the past.  After the latest Ubuntu 22.04 LTS update of Libreoffice, the extension was missing.  When I downloaded the extension from Liberoffice, the extension fails to load due to the java error displayed in the screenshot in this post.  Any workarounds/fixes?  Any assistance would be appreciated.

Did you just upgrade to 22.04? Or were you using 22.04 all along and libreoffice had an update?

I have been using 22.04 since it was available as a "no fresh install" upgrade to 20.04 and shall be doing the same for 24.04 LTS.  LibreOffice has been working fine and production updated as Software Update made available, but I needed to produce Latex.  When I looked at the installed LibreOffice, no Latex -- the extension had been removed during a Software Updater update.  I then downloaded the Latex OTX, and it would no longer install with the "Java" diagnostic exception (error) visible in the screenshot I posted to this list.  Is the above clear?

Please ask the question here https://ask.libreoffice.org/c/english/5 as well.

Can you try upgrading to the latest libreoffice version using this PPA and let us know if the issue exists there? https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/ubuntu/ppa
